# How to get elapsed time for a Hadoop task on local mode?

Tags: java, hadoop, word-count, bigdata

Hi I am trying to run the WordCount program with Hadoop in **local/standalone** mode and I want to see the time needed for the task. I'm using the code from the Hadoop website. I tried adding this at the end of the code but it prints out 0.

```
job.waitForCompletion(true);
long time = job.getFinishTime() - job.getStartTime();
System.out.println("Time taken = " + time);
```

I also tried this method but it prints out nothing instead.

```
job.waitForCompletion(); 

TaskReport[] reports = job.getTaskReports(TaskType.MAP);
for(TaskReport report : reports) { 
   long time = report.getFinishTime() - report.getStartTime();
   System.out.println(report.getTaskId() + " took " + time + " millis!");
}
```

Is there another way to see the elapsed time in milliseconds in Hadoop standalone mode? Many thanks!